# Solving linear differential inequality using linear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I would like to solve the linear differential inequality:
$$a_0y(x)+a_1y'(x)+...a_ny^{(n)}(x)\le f(x)$$

satisfied for all $x\in X$, where $X$ is some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my idea how to solve it. I would like to know whether this is a good idea.

> Is this true that the solution are in the form
> $$y(x)\le g(x)$$ for all $x\in X$
> where $g(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation:
> $$a_0y(x)+a_1y'(x)+...a_ny^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$$

If this is a bad idea, then how are the techniques of solving that kind of inequality.

Regards

Comment: I think you need to include the initial conditions, i.e. $y(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ if $y(x_0)\le g(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in X$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the solutions are in general not in the form $y(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=0$, $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 > 0$,  and $a_n=0$ for $n\ge2$. Then, the solutions for

$$g(x)+a_1 g'(x) = 0$$

are exponentials $g(x)=g_0\exp\left(-\frac{1}{a_1}x\right)$ with $g(0)=g_0$. Let $g_0>0$, Now,

$$y(x) = g_0\exp\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}x\right)$$

with $0<b_1<a_1$ and $y(0) = g(0)$ fulfills the inequality

$$y(x)+a_1 y'(x) \le 0$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, because $1-\frac{a1}{b1}\le 0$. But, $(\frac{1}{b_1}-\frac{1}{a_1})x<0$ for $x<0$ and, thus,

\begin{eqnarray}
g_0\exp\left(-\frac{1}{a_1}x\right)&<&g_0\exp\left(-\frac{1}{b_1}x\right)\\
g(x) &<& y(x)
\end{eqnarray}
for $x<0$.